# new line character in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, newline

I need to call a method from a java bean that returns a string composed of multiple lines

However I need to insert the newline character in the JSP Form.

In java bean, I am using the following method:

```
for (String s : descriptionContrats){
        if(s.startsWith("Contrat")){                        
            contratsBuilder.append(s+"\r\n ");  

         }                  
 }  
 contrats=contratsBuilder.toString();
```

I wish to display the string `contrats` in multiple lines according to the number of iterations

But when the variable is called in JSP and I use it in the following manner:

```
<tr><td><%- contrats %> </td></tr>
```

It prints simply as a single string in a single line.

**Update**

I have already replaced `contratsBuilder.append(s+"\r\n ");` by `contratsBuilder.append(s).append("<br/>");` but  my `<br />` tags getting converted to `&lt;br /&gt;` in the html. However when it renders on browser, it has the `<br />` and therefore there is no line break???.

Comment: Why do you want to return string? Return collection instead and iterate it on jsp.

Comment: @AleksandrM How to iterate a list of String in jsp????

Comment: By using some taglib (e.g. jstl).

Comment: @juniorengineer I edited the question to make the <br /> you're talking about visible. Hope this is what you meant; otherwise, feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 4):

You are displaying the page in HTML, so you need to use HTML's newline tag - `<br/>`:

```
for (String s : descriptionContrats) {
    if (s.startsWith("Contrat")) {
        contratsBuilder.append(s).append("<br/>");
    }
}  
contrats = contratsBuilder.toString();
```